# Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ given by $X_1 = (0,1)\cup(3,4)$ and $X_2 = (0,1)\cup(1,2)$. Is $X_1 \cong X_2 $?

Tags: general-topology

Correct me if im wrong, but intuitively i think that it's not a homeomorphism between $X_1 \cong X_2 $, nevertheless i need a more rigorous answer to this. Anyone who has a suggestion or idea please share it.

Comment: What is the picture for? Isn't this in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why would it not be a homeomorphism? Note that the points you have chosen to denote with blue dots are not included in either $X_1$ or $X_2$ (sometimes we use open circles to show this).

Comment: You're right, I did not realize. so dumb hahaha

Comment: It’s also not hard to write down an explicit homeo.

Comment: my chart is wrong I'm going to remove it

Comment: @Randall, can you explain or give some advice. thks

Comment: You can even write an isomorphism!: $$f(x\in X_1) = x + 2\lfloor x\rfloor\in X_2$$

Comment: @MichaelLee you are right, but i did not find open dot on geogebra

Comment: having two open disjoint sets is like having a sum topology. Here both components are just open intervals (i.e. topologically the reals), so it's just $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ in disguise in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x & \text{if}~~~ x\in (0,1),\\
x+2 &\text{if}~~~ x\in (1,2)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

is a continuous bijection from $(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ to $(0,1)\cup (3,4),$ with a continuous inverse

$$f^{-1}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x & \text{if}~~~ x\in (0,1),\\
x-2 &\text{if}~~~ x\in (3,4).
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And so $(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ and $(0,1)\cup (3,4)$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!